# python loop over a list ( show the total 30 days with weekdays)

Tags: python

```
list = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
```

I want to show the total 30 days with weekdays, can somebody tell me how to do that in for or while loop ? Thanks

the output I want is :

```
day 0 : Sun
day 1 : Mon
day 2 : Tue
day 3 : Wed
day 4 : Thu
day 5 : Fri
day 6 : Sat
day 7 : Sun
day 8 : Mon
day 9 : Tue
day 10 : Wed
day 11 : Thu
day 12 : Fri
...
...
day 30 :
```

my code :

```
     a = 0
     for i in range(0,30):
         print("Day",str(i),list[a])
         a += 1
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tracker.py", line 25, in <module>
    print("Day",str(i),weekdays[day_number])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Your error message is not actually from the code you posted. Please provide the actual error message your code generates and post that identical code, both completely and in form of a [repro].

Comment: Basically, `a` = `i`, since you increment `a` in the loop. `list` is of length 7, so when `a` becomes >=7, `list[a]` tries to access an element beyond the end of the list (as the error message is telling you). You should add a test to reset `a` to 0 when = 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
monthdays = 30
day_index = 6
for i in range(monthdays):
    day_index = (day_index + 1) % 7
    day = weekdays[day_index]
    print("day", i, day)
```

day_index is 6, because you start with sunday, but you can change it.

Also there is no need to call `str(i)` inside `print`, it does it for you.

Comment: Instead of making `day_index` a separate variable, you can just use `weekdays[i % 7]`. (Either way, you don't want the `+ 1` in there; that starts the output on Saturday.)

Comment: Yeah you're right, didn't notice the weekdays definition and assumed the list started with monday :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to print `weekdays[7]` when `weekdays` only has seven elements (i.e. `weekdays[0]` to `weekdays[6]`).

There are many ways to solve this problem, but in this case, the simplest is the best.

In your loop, use `weekdays[i % len(weekdays)]` instead of `weekdays[i]`.

The [modulo (mod) operator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#index-66) finds the remainder of produced when dividing its arguments. This produces a looping behavior.

```
n | n % 3 |
--+-------+
0 |   0   |  0 = 0 * 3 + [0]
1 |   1   |  1 = 0 * 3 + [1]
2 |   2   |  2 = 0 * 3 + [2]
3 |   0   |  3 = 1 * 3 + [0]
4 |   1   |  4 = 1 * 3 + [1]
5 |   2   |
6 |   0   |
7 |   1   |
8 |   2   |
9 |   0   |
```

So when you reach indexes past the length of the `some_list`, an index of `i % len(some_list)` will loop back around to 0 and let you keep going.